Problem Uploading PDF Files to WordPress: Stuck Loading
I'm experiencing an issue with uploading PDF files to my WordPress site. Previously, I could upload PDF files without any problem, but recently, the upload starts and gets stuck, with no progress. Additionally, no files appear in the media library.
I've checked the settings in my php.ini file, and here’s what I found:
upload_max_filesize = 128M post_max_size = 128M memory_limit = 512M
Are there any other PHP settings I should check regarding file uploads?
Are there any error logs in WordPress or on the server that could provide more information about what's happening during the upload?
Thank you in advance for your help!

did you hit any server quota? Like innodes or drive space? Maybe you hit a firewall? Contact your hosting would be your best bet.
